# Woocommerce pay by invoice per user

Tags: woocommerce, invoice

I'm looking for a plugin which allows my customers to pay by invoice, but I want manually enable that option per user.

Is there an plugin for available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin which made this possible!

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommere-invoice-me-for-selected-customers/9360130